# How can I redirect a result of a Mongo variable to a collection, and then export it to a csv file

Tags: mongodb

I have a beginner MongoDB question, but I am really stuck on this.

So, I have a dataset of some medical data
[image: dataset]
and I need to calculate the averages and the standard deviations for the each column and store it in a table represented below.
[image: a result I wish to get]

So, I have made an aggregation

```
var average_age = db.ilp.aggregate(
{$match: {"age":{$ne:-1}}},
{"$group":{
"_id": null, 
"avg_age": {"$avg":"$age"}
}
})
```

tried to store it into a variable and I get the following output for this variable:
`{ "_id" : null, "avg_age" : 44.74614065180103 }`

But when I want to insert this into a new collection, by `db.test.insert(average_age)`, I get the following output:
[image: output]

After I make a desired collection, I want to redirect it to a csv file.

I appreciate any help you could provide.

P.S. also, I can you tell me why, first time when I call the variable average_age, it outputs the correct value showed above, and after that when I call it, it doesn't output anything, like it is empty.

Comment: Please input data at jsoneeditor online ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add as last pipeline [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) operator.

```
db.ilp.aggregate([
    {$match: {"age":{$ne:-1}}},
    {"$group":{
        "_id": null, 
        "avg_age": {"$avg":"$age"}
    },
    {$out: "collection-name"}
])
```

When you assign `db.ilp.aggregate(...)`or call `db.ilp.find(...)` methods, MongoDB returns [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/index.html).

[cursor.toArray()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray) returns an array that contains all the documents from a cursor

```
var average_age = db.ilp.aggregate(...).toArray();
```

**Note:**  Do not use `$out` stage if you wish get all results

Comment: When I use $out the way you showed, I get a syntax error, "expected property name, got '{' :". Although I just wrote that line of code with $out. Also, what do you mean that I do not use $out if I wish to get all results?

Comment: There was a syntax error in the aggregation, I corrected it (it was missing the array brackets).

Comment: The problem was with the last } bracket, it should look like this "  db.ilp.aggregate([
    {$match: {"age":{$ne:-1}}},
    {"$group":{
        "_id": null, 
        "avg_age": {"$avg":"$age"}
    }},
    {$out: "collection-name"}
])   ". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Valijon's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59547485/1417546), you also have the option of [creating a view](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/index.html) and use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/index.html) to save the collection as a CSV file directly. This has the advantage that you can export the view many times, updating the averages every time you export it:

```
db.createView('ilp_averages', 'ilp', [
  { $match: { "age": { $ne:-1 } } },
  {"$group": {
    "_id": null, 
    "avg_age": {"$avg":"$age"}
  }])
```

And export with:

```
mongoexport --host <mongodbinstance>:<port> --type csv -d=<yourdb> -c=ilp_averages -o=ilp_averages.csv
```

Note that the correct syntax for mongoexport depends on the version of MongoDB that you are using, there could be slight variations.